# How do I install the eID software on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I am new to Linux. I am trying to  install eID software using these commands

```
sudo apt install eid-mw eid-viewer
sudo dpkg -i Downloads / eid-archive_2020.1_all_1.deb
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg -i Downloads / eid-archive_2020.1_all_1.deb
sudo apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer
```

the probem is with the second command
I got this
dpkg: error: archive 'Downloads' is not a regular file

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: What is eID software? Which guide do you follow? From where do you get its deb-packages? Have you tried to remove spaces to install `sudo dpkg -i Downloads/eid-archive_2020.1_all_1.deb`?

Comment: eID software is the Belgian ID card reader , which allows you to access some government websites.   Here you are the guide like https://peterlinux.blogspot.com/2019/06/eid-instaleren-op-ubuntu-1804.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install [eID](https://eid.belgium.be/en/linux-eid-software-installation) you need to open terminal and execute the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://eid.belgium.be/sites/default/files/software/eid-archive_2020.4_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./eid-archive_2020.4_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked !